# tensorflow keras: I am getting this error 'module "tensorflow._api.v1.keras.layers' has no attribute 'flatten'"

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I am getting the above error while executing the below code.
I am trying to work out this below tutorial on tensorflow neural network implementation.
https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/tensorflow-tutorial

```
def load_data(data_directory):
directories = [d for d in os.listdir(data_directory) 
               if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(data_directory, d))]
labels = []
images = []
for d in directories:
    label_directory = os.path.join(data_directory, d)
    file_names = [os.path.join(label_directory, f) 
                  for f in os.listdir(label_directory) 
                  if f.endswith(".ppm")]
    for f in file_names:
        images.append(skimage.data.imread(f))
        labels.append(int(d))
return images, labels

import os
import skimage
from skimage import transform
from skimage.color import rgb2gray
import numpy as np
import keras
from keras import layers
from keras.layers import Dense
ROOT_PATH = "C://Users//Jay//AppData//Local//Programs//Python//Python37//Scriptcodes//BelgianSignals"
train_data_directory = os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, "Training")
test_data_directory = os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, "Testing")

images, labels = load_data(train_data_directory)


# Print the `labels` dimensions
print(np.array(labels))

# Print the number of `labels`'s elements
print(np.array(labels).size)

# Count the number of labels
print(len(set(np.array(labels))))

# Print the `images` dimensions
print(np.array(images))

# Print the number of `images`'s elements
print(np.array(images).size)

# Print the first instance of `images`
np.array(images)[0]

images28 = [transform.resize(image, (28, 28)) for image in images]

images28 = np.array(images28)

images28 = rgb2gray(images28)

# Import `tensorflow` 
import tensorflow as tf 

# Initialize placeholders 
x = tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.float32, shape = [None, 28, 28])
y = tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.int32, shape = [None])

# Flatten the input data
images_flat = tf.keras.layers.flatten(x)

# Fully connected layer 
logits = tf.contrib.layers.dense(images_flat, 62, tf.nn.relu)

# Define a loss function
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels = y, 
                                                                    logits = logits))
# Define an optimizer 
train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001).minimize(loss)

# Convert logits to label indexes
correct_pred = tf.argmax(logits, 1)

# Define an accuracy metric
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))
```

At first, I used tf.layers.flatten(x) as in the tutorial. however, it will be depreciated in future versions. So add keras instead as suggested.

I am getting the following output in IDLE Console.

RESTART: C:\Users\Jay\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scriptcodes\SecondTensorFlow.py 
Using TensorFlow backend.

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\Jay\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\skimage\transform_warps.py", line 105
    warn("The default mode, 'constant', will be changed to 'reflect' in "
UserWarning: The default mode, 'constant', will be changed to 'reflect' in skimage 0.15.

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\Jay\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\skimage\transform_warps.py", line 110
    warn("Anti-aliasing will be enabled by default in skimage 0.15 to "
UserWarning: Anti-aliasing will be enabled by default in skimage 0.15 to avoid aliasing artifacts when down-sampling images.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jay\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scriptcodes\SecondTensorFlow.py", line 64, in

images_flat = tf.python.keras.layers.flatten(x)

**AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'python'**

I am using,
Keras version 2.2.4
Tensorflow version 1.13.1

Comment: Use `Flatten` with capital `F` here:-  images_flat = tf.keras.layers.flatten(x)

Comment: Nope, it isn't working. Its failing with the below error.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "*\SecondTensorFlow.py", line 63, in <module>
    images_flat = tf.keras.layers.Flatten(x)
  File "C:\Users\Jay\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\layers\core.py", line 539, in __init__
    self.data_format = conv_utils.normalize_data_format(data_format)
  File "C:\Users\Jay\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\utils\conv_utils.py", line 188, in normalize_data_format
    data_format = value.lower()
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'lower'

Comment: There's no such thing as "tf.python"; where did you get this code from?

Answer (score 1):

Either

`from keras.layers import Flatten`

and use

`Flatten()(input)`

or

simply use

`tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(input)`

Answer (score 0):

The new ("keras as the default API") approach would have you use the keras layer `tf.keras.layers.Flatten` but there is a little nuance you seem to have missed (and that hasn't been mentioned in the comments).

`tf.keras.layers.Flatten()` actually returns a keras layer (callable) object which in turn needs to be called with your previous layer.

So something more like this:

```py
# Flatten the input data
flatten_layer = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()
images_flat = flatten_layer(x)
```

or, for brevity, just:

```py
# Flatten the input data
images_flat = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(x)
```